# Compare csv and text file and replace updated value in python

Tags: python, csv, text, compare, key

I have 2 files, one csv file and one text file. I'm looking for a way to compare them using two specific columns, and once a match is found I need to take the value of another column from the matched row and put it in the corresponding column of the other record.

The csv has location,time,value
The txt has location,time,value as well

I need to compare the 2 files by finding the rows that have a matching location and time, once found I need to take the value from csv file and put it to the matched record's value in txt file.

Here's two files. Book1.csv and book2.txt.

---

```
Book1.csv

LOCATION         TIME        VALUE

A   3/7/2014 7:00   -4.2

  B 3/8/2014 4:00   -5.4
```

---

```
book2.txt

D,MSSDATA,ZONE,LOCATION       ,TIME,VALUE

D,MSSDATA,ZONE,A              ,3/7/2014 7:00,13

D,MSSDATA,ZONE,B              ,3/7/2014 7:00,21
```

---

Both files have LOCATION, TIME and VALUE.

What I want to do is that: compare two files, if LOCATION and TIME is same, replace the VALUE in book2.txt with VALUE in Book1.csv

For example. For location A, TIME 3/7/2014 7:00, I would like to replace VALUE in book2.txt, which is "13" with load in Book1.csv, which is -4.2

For location B  TIME 3/7/2014 7:00, I couldn't fine match data in Book1.csv. so it wouldn't be changed.

---

Finally, I would like book2.txt as follows:

```
D,MSSDATA,ZONE,1.0,LOCATION                 ,TIME,LOAD

D,MSSDATA,ZONE,1.0,A                     ,3/7/2014 7:00,-4.2

D,MSSDATA,ZONE,1.0,B                     ,3/7/2014 7:00,21
```

---

I have written some basic code as follows to read the file, but how to compare and replace still bothers me. I guess i need to create a dictionary with keys {Location, time}

Really appreciate someone could help!  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Wendy. You'll get a better response if you show us your code, and ask a specific question about the bit that troubles you.

Comment: Are the lines sorted by LOCATION, TIME? Is it ok to load the whole files in memory?

Comment: Have you tried `csv` module to read both files?

Comment: the whole files is big, has 20000 lines